# If Realmwright is removed from the battlefield, do the changed lands remain dual colored?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I just came by [Realmwright](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Realmwright) and it didn't give any discussion on whether the changed lands are permanently changed or not if the creature leaves the battlefield.

Does anyone have any info on this?

Comment: Realmwright doesn't change any land's color. They remain colorless.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer is *no*, they'll lose whatever type they're given when Realmwright leaves the battlefield. The reason is that Realmwright has a *static ability* that creates a continuous effect that dictates that the lands are of the given type:

> 112.3d Static abilities are written as statements. They're simply true. Static abilities create continuous effects which are active
>   while the permanent with the ability is on the battlefield and has the
>   ability, or while the object with the ability is in the appropriate
>   zone. See rule 604, "Handling Static Abilities."

Since Realmwright's ability is the source of the continuous effect giving the lands the specified type, the effect will end as soon as Realmwright leaves the battlefield.

Comment: But what verbiage am I looking for to see that its a static ability?

Comment: The text 'Lands you control are the chosen type in addition to their other types' is the static ability text.  It's a static ability 'by default': because it doesn't use the phrase 'when', it isn't a triggered ability; because it doesn't have the colon it's not an activated ability; and abilities that last 'forever' (i.e., that aren't tied to a permanent being in the appropriate zone) are (generally) expressed with _emblems_ now.  For more information on how to identify abilities, I suggest reading the rest of section 112 in the comprehensive rules.

Comment: You might want to look at a card like Obsidian Fireheart (http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=192224) for an example of how a Magic card needs to *specifically clarify* that an effect continues even after the generating permanent has left play.